# How to place a "canplaceon" tag on villager's trades

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to make an adventure map, and I want to do a merchant with blocks who contains the "Canplaceon" tag

Comment: So you want a villager selling blocks with a canplaceon tag?

Comment: Yup, That's it !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do I put item tags on items inside a chest or your inventory?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272179/where-do-i-put-item-tags-on-items-inside-a-chest-or-your-inventory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done, but manipulating villager trades in the first place is... tricky.

First of all, we need a villager. So, let's use the `/summon` command to get a villager. Remember, `/summon` takes coordinates, an entity ID, and a NBT tag. Our main concern is the NBT tag, which is what allows us to specify exactly what we want our guy to do. Obviously our base command will be `/summon Villager X Y Z {tag}`. For the rest of this answer, I'm just going to explore the `{tag}` portion of the command.

Villagers have an `Offers:` tag inside their NBT data, which has a `Recipes:` list of compound tags. So, that's where we're going to want to start. Let's say you want this guy to sell 64 stone bricks for 3 emeralds (I'll get to modifying NBT in a second). Our NBT tag will look like this:

```
{Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:minecraft:emerald,Count:3},sell:{id:minecraft:stone,Count:64}}]}}
```

Let's break that down here:

```
{Offers:{
    Recipes:[
        {buy:{id:minecraft:emerald,Count:3},
         sell:{id:minecraft:stone,Count:64}
        }
    ]}
}
```

`Recipes:` is a list of compound tags containing trade offers. `buy:` is a compound tag that contains the NBT for the item the villager wants. `sell:` is a compound tag for the NBT data of the item being sold. So, from here, we can add our `CanPlaceOn` tag:

```
{Offers:{
    Recipes:[
        {buy:{id:minecraft:emerald,Count:3},
         sell:{id:minecraft:stone,Count:64,tag:{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:dirt","minecraft:stone"]}}
        }
    ]}
}
```

I'll let you set up your own `CanPlaceOn` list, since unfortunately there isn't a `CanPlace` tag that covers all cases.

The problem now, is he will still unlock his future pre-coded trades. To fix this, we need to set his `CareerLevel` really high:

```
{CareerLevel:6,
Offers:{
    Recipes:[
        {buy:{id:minecraft:emerald,Count:3},
         sell:{id:minecraft:stone,Count:64,tag:{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:dirt","minecraft:stone"]}}
        }
    ]}
}
```

This will cause our villager to ignore his pre-defined trades. Now, all we need to do is glue our command back together:

```
/summon Villager ~ ~ ~ {CareerLevel:6,Offers:{Recipes:[{buy:{id:minecraft:emerald,Count:3},sell:{id:minecraft:stone,Count:64,tag:{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:dirt","minecraft:stone"]}}}]}}
```